# Use wildcard with os.path.isfile()

Tags: python, path, wildcard

I'd like to check if there are any `.rar` files in a directory. It doesn’t need to be recursive.

Using wildcard with `os.path.isfile()` was my best guess, but it doesn't work. What can I do then?

Comment: You should accept an answer to this question...

Answer (score 111):

[glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) is what you need.

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('*.rar')   # all rar files within the directory, in this case the current working one
```

`os.path.isfile()` returns `True` if a path is an existing regular file. So that is used for checking whether a file already exists and doesn't support wildcards. `glob` does.

Comment: +1 you just beat me to it while I was trying to pull a complete answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, without using os.path.isfile() to check the results, you still don't know whether what you've found are directories or files.

Answer (score 19):

Without using [`os.path.isfile()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) you won't know whether the results returned by [`glob()`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) are files or subdirectories, so try something like this instead:

```
import fnmatch
import os

def find_files(base, pattern):
    '''Return list of files matching pattern in base folder.'''
    return [n for n in fnmatch.filter(os.listdir(base), pattern) if
        os.path.isfile(os.path.join(base, n))]

rar_files = find_files('somedir', '*.rar')
```

You could also just filter the results returned by `glob()` if you like, and that has the advantage of doing a few extra things relating to unicode and the like.  Check the source in glob.py if it matters.

```
[n for n in glob(pattern) if os.path.isfile(n)]
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `glob.glob`?

Comment: @Lou Sure, in real code, if you like. Code snippets are often simplified for clarity. In this case, an implied "from glob import glob" came first...

Answer (score 10):

```
import os
[x for x in os.listdir("your_directory") if len(x) >= 4 and  x[-4:] == ".rar"]
```

Comment: Since  `os ` has mostly already been imported, this is  a lean & clean solution for me.

Comment: My case was somewhat different than the OP, but this answer was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

**Wildcards are expanded by shell** and hence you can not use it with os.path.isfile()

If you want to use wildcards, you could use `popen with shell = True` or `os.system()`

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('ls')
aliases.sh          
default_bashprofile     networkhelpers          projecthelper.old           pythonhelpers           virtualenvwrapper_bashrc
0
>>> os.system('ls *.old')
projecthelper.old
0
```

You could get the same effect with glob module too.

```
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob('*.old')
['projecthelper.old']
>>>
```

Comment: Isn't that a bit too OS-dependent?

Answer (score 4):

If you just care about whether at least one file exists and you don't want a list of the files:

```
import glob
import os

def check_for_files(filepath):
    for filepath_object in glob.glob(filepath):
        if os.path.isfile(filepath_object):
            return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

to display full path and filter based on extension,

```
import os
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(file) if len(f) >= 5 and  f[-5:] == ".json" and isfile(join(file, f))]
```

Answer (score -1):

iglob is better than glob here since you do not actually want the full list of rar files, but just want to check that one rar exists

Comment: While this is actually true, this answer would benefit from a more-detailed explanation.  The difference is that `iglob` returns an iterator, so if you call it once and it returns something, you know there was at least one match.

Answer (score -1):

Just another method to get the job done using subprocess.

```
import subprocess

try:
        q = subprocess.check_output('ls')
        if ".rar" in q:
             print "Rar exists"
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        print e.output
```

Reference : https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output