# how can I find whether there is any txt file in a directory or not with Python

Tags: python, file, directory, file-exists

I would like to find that whether there is any file exists in a specific directory or not with using python.

Something like this;

```
if os.path.exists('*.txt'):
   # true --> do something
else:
   # false --> do something
```

Comment: do you mean "any file" or "any txt file"?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. I meant any text file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use wildcard with os.path.isfile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296138/use-wildcard-with-os-path-isfile)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `glob.glob` with wildcards and check whether it returns anything. For instance:

```
import glob
if glob.glob('*.txt'):
    # file(s) exist -> do something
else:
    # no files found
```

Note that `glob.glob` return a list of files matching the wildcard (or an empty list).

Comment: actually, AshwiniChaudhary's solution is more efficient (doesn't generate an unused list).

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`glob.iglob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.iglob) with [`next`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
import glob
if next(glob.iglob('*.txt'), False):
     #do something
else:
     #do something else
```

Here if `glog.iglob` returns an empty iterator then the default value `False` will be used.

or as @user2357112 suggested in comments, we can simply use `any` as it returns `False` for an empty iterable.:

```
if any(glob.iglob('*.txt')):
     #do something
else:
     #do something else
```

Comment: Why not just `any` the iterator?

Answer (score 0):

[os.listdir()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) will get you everything that's in a directory - files and directories

```
import os
if not os.listdir(dir):
    #do something
else:
    #do something
```

Comment: This seems not correct. It does not distinct a directory with .txt files from a directory with only other files.

Answer (score 0):

For those getting here from google there is another solution you can use for checking if a glob is empty or not.

The previous answers are sufficient in themselves, however you can also determine the amount of files returned by a glob using [len()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/len), and use that as a comparison.

```
if(len(glob.glob('*.txt')) == 0):
    #Glob has no files
else:
    #Continue
```

This will let you confirm if the glob does, or does not, have files. This also lets you confirm that the glob has more than or less than a specific quantity of files, should you need to do so.

Comment: This seems redundant - although I must admit that if you know nothing about what glob does, this is more immediately readable. I'd be curious to see whether there are time differences.