# how to use wild cards if file exists .py

Tags: wildcard

I'm trying to find out what is the best way to use the wild cards in Python. I'm trying to migrate this piece of .ks code to .py. If *any* file in a folder exists. I was thinking using these alternatives like:
glob
os.path.exists = but this will turn true or false
os.path.isfile
len?
Here is part my code.

```
#this is .ks
fail_flag=0
#Checking more than one file of any kind
files=$(ls /opt/flag/*)  
for file in $file
do
 if [ -f $file ] ; then
  fail_flag=1
 fi
done
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use wildcard with os.path.isfile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296138/use-wildcard-with-os-path-isfile)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you can use python glob.
Something like that:

```
import glob
if glob.glob('//opt//flag//*.*'):
   return True
```

Here is the docs - https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html