# Interpret path with * in Windows with Python

Tags: python, windows, path

I am trying to find the full real path on Windows, based on a path with the `*` character in it (which seems to be something similar to a regular expression).

For instance, if in a Windows console I do:

```
cd C:\\Windows\\Program Files\\MySWv1*\\bin
```

the above path is expanded in something like:

```
C:\\Windows\\Program Files\\MySWv1.90\\bin
```

and then the `cd` command is executed successfully.

However, if in Python (2.7) I try to execute the following:

```
import os
my_path = 'C:\\Windows\\Program Files\\MySWv1*\\bin'
os.path.exists(my_path)
```

This returns `False`.

How can I make the above script returns `True`?

Comment: Wildcards are expanded by shell and hence you can not use it with os.path.exists()

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/a/4296148/3896984

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296138/use-wildcard-with-os-path-isfile). It is based on the `glob` module:

```
import os
import glob
my_path = glob.glob('C:\\Windows\\Program Files\\MySWv1*\\bin')[0]
os.path.exists(my_path)
```

Actually, [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html#glob.glob) interprets the path and substitutes any wildcards (like `*`) with one **or more** strings, resulting in a **list** of paths that match them.

This means that, in production code, you should always take into account the possibility that more than one path is produced by `glob.glob`, and, if needed, do something to manage this rule.

Comment: The result of `glob` is a list, and if the list is non-empty the items surely existed *at the time*. In a multithreaded OS there's no guarantee that they still exist. It's best to try the operation and handle the exception.