# Wait till download is complete in Python+Selenium+Firefox

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, firefox

I want to close browser as soon file download is complete. I have below code but it's not closing browser. I must be wrong somewhere. Please help me.

```
driver.find_element_by_link_text("[Comma-Delimited Text (CSV)]").click()
while True:
    if os.path.isfile('C:\\Python34\\*.part'):
        time.sleep(10)
    elif os.path.isfile('C:\\Python34\\*.csv'):
        break
    else:
        time.sleep(10)


def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
    self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`os.path.isfile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) *does not support glob-style path definitions* leading to the loop never exiting.

You need the `glob.glob()` or `fnmatch` instead:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4296148/771848

You can also use modules like [`watchdog`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) to monitor changes in a directory:

- [python selenium, find out when a download has completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338897/python-selenium-find-out-when-a-download-has-completed)

Comment: Just what I wanted, it's very helpful when file download is anywhere between some seconds to some minutes. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I have written a download method for zip file download. this could be helpful. after clicking on download button this method will be called and waiting until the download complete

```
def downloader() :
    print("File Download Started.......")
    sleep(60)
    while True:
        file = glob.glob(BASE_FILE_DIR+'*.zip.part')
        if file:
            print("Download Pending.......")
            sleep(60)
            continue
        else:
            print('File Downloaded')
            break
```