# How I can get real img file name by src in Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Using LogoImg.GetAttribute("src") I get the following scr:

https://scol.stage-next.sc.local/lspprofile/5a2e7338d6e9a927741175e2/image?id=5a2fbc98d6e9a9177c8c1592

But the real name of the file is: TestImage - 9fb0c49d-69b1-49ed-8c63-4283e405b781.jpg

If i enter the src in my browser i got the file with real name downloaded.
How can I get the real name of the file in selenium as I need it for test.

Well the task is solved by other means, i just compared the differences in src. But the responce to the question would be yet interesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are able to retrieve the `src` attribute as follows :

```
https://scol.stage-next.sc.local/lspprofile/5a2e7338d6e9a927741175e2/image?id=5a2fbc98d6e9a9177c8c1592
```

This is the reference to the resource stored in the Database. So it wouldn't be possible to retrive the name **`9fb0c49d-69b1-49ed-8c63-4283e405b781.jpg`** before the file gets downloaded.

To ensure the download is completed and then to read the **`filename`** you will need to use either of the following :

- `glob.glob()` or `fnmatch` :

  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4296148/771848
- `Watchdog` module to monitor changes with in a directory:

  [python selenium, find out when a download has completed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34338897/python-selenium-find-out-when-a-download-has-completed)